# How to create zip archive with files with only .txt extension in Linux using terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, zip

I have directory "Documents" with these files:

file1.txt.

file2.txt

index.html

index.php

script.pl

I want to create zip archive named files.zip with only .txt extension files using terminal. How can I do these?

Comment: should it find `.txt` files in subfolders also?

Comment: Yes. For example in this same directory (Documents) I have one directory named files. These direcrory contains files with .txt extensions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the basic level, if you are in the same directory that your files are in, you can do :

```
zip files.zip *txt
```

And if you want to zip the files with `.txt` extention, by giving the absolute path, if they are in `Documents` directory, which will create `files.zip` in the current directory you are in:

```
zip files.zip /the/path/to/Documents/*txt
```

If you also want this zipped file to be in `Documents` folder, you should specify it as:

```
zip /the/path/to/Documents/files.zip /the/path/to/Documents/*txt
```

Answer (score 0):

An add-on to the existing answer, if you are adding to an existing zip archive, **be careful** if you have identically named entries in the zip **archive** & the **inpath**. From `man zip`:

> Command format.  The basic command format is
>
> ```
>    zip options archive inpath inpath ...
> ```
>
> where  archive is a new or existing zip archive and inpath is a directory or file path optionally including wildcards.  When given the
> name of an ***existing*** zip archive, zip ***will replace*** iden‐
> tically named entries in the zip archive (matching the relative names as stored in the archive) or add entries for new names.  For
> example, if  foo.zip  exists  and  contains  foo/file1  and
> foo/file2, and the directory foo contains the files foo/file1 and foo/file3, then:
>
> ```
>    zip -r foo.zip foo
> ```
>
> or more concisely
>
> ```
>    zip -r foo foo
> ```
>
> will replace foo/file1 in foo.zip and add foo/file3 to foo.zip.  After this, foo.zip contains foo/file1, foo/file2, and foo/file3, with
> foo/file2 unchanged from before.
>
> So if before the zip command is executed foo.zip has:
>
> ```
>    foo/file1 foo/file2
> ```
>
> and directory foo has:
>
> ```
>    file1 file3
> ```
>
> then foo.zip will have:
>
> ```
>    foo/file1 foo/file2 foo/file3
> ```
>
> where foo/file1 is replaced and foo/file3 is new.

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to:

```
zip only-txt.zip `find . -name "*.txt"`
```

This will create a zip file named `only-txt.zip` including all the `*.txt` files located within the directory you run the command, notice that this will search for *.txt files recursively in all subfolders of the dir